# Ошибка при попытке вывести endl: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘A’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)

Tags: c++

Хочу написать класс обертку, который в зависимости от переменных будет или не будет выводить лог в `stdout` и/или файл `log.txt`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  bool use_log = 1, use_filelog = 0;
  ofstream log_file;
  void open() {
    use_filelog = 1;
    log_file.open("log.txt");
  }
};

template <class T> A &operator<<(A &a, T x) {
  if (a.use_log) {
    std::cout << x;
  }
  if (a.use_filelog) {
    a.log_file << x;
  }
  return a;
}

int main() {
  A a;
  a << "Hello, World!" << endl; // <= ERROR
}
```

Получаю ошибку при попытке вывести `endl`. В чём проблема не пойму.

Может данный класс можно реализовать как-нибудь по другому?

Вот начало полотна вывода от `gcc`:

```
4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
4.cpp:26:24: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘A’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)
   a << "Hello, World!" << endl;
                        ^
4.cpp:14:23: note: candidate: template<class T> A& operator<<(A&, T)
 template <class T> A &operator<<(A &a, T x) {
                       ^
4.cpp:14:23: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
4.cpp:26:27: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
   a << "Hello, World!" << endl;
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from 4.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:628:5: note: candidate: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Tp> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&)
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

А вот от `clang`:

```
prog.cpp:26:27: error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?
  a << "Hello, World!" << endl;
                          ^~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:590:5: note: possible target for call
    endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
    ^
prog.cpp:14:23: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
template <class T> A &operator<<(A &a, T x) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::endl` не имеет конкретного типа, ибо само по себе [является шаблоном функции](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl). Поэтому запись вида

```
a << endl;
```

является неоднозначной и вывести параметры шаблонов из нее невозможно. О чем вам и говорит компилятор. Чтобы устранить неоднозначность вам придется указывать параметры хотя бы одного из шаблонов явно.

Например, если вы явно укажете параметры шаблона `std::endl`

```
a << std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>;
```

то ваш тип `T` успешно дедуцируется и ваш оператор сработает, как задумано.

Но чтобы не извращаться подобным образом в реальности, можно поступить [по аналогии со стандартными потоками](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) и создать еще один оператор вывода, специально предназначенный для вывода `std::endl`

```
A &operator <<(A &a, 
               std::basic_ostream<char>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<char>&))
{
  if (a.use_log) {
    std::cout << func;
  }
  if (a.use_filelog) {
    a.log_file << func;
  }      
  return a;
}
```

При этом реализацию этого оператора, после того как параметры шаблона `std::endl` уже зафиксировались, можно не выписывать явно, а делегировать в ваш шаблонный оператор (здесь нужно быть аккуратным, чтобы не устроить рекурсию)

```
A &operator <<(A &a, 
               std::basic_ostream<char>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<char>&))
{
  return operator << <>(a, func);
}
```

А чтобы поддержать и остальные манипуляторы, придется реализовать и остальные операторы группы 10-12 по ссылке.

Comment: Написал `operator <<(a, func);` вместо `operator << <>(a, func);`, и получил ошибку выполнения: `Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)`. Интересно из-за чего?

Comment: @pank: Именно из-за того, что `operator <<(a, func)` - это рекурсивный вызов самого себя - бесконечная рекурсия со всеми вытекающими. А вариант `operator << <>(a, func)` явно заставляет компилятор вызвать именно *шаблонную* версию оператора. Именно поэтому я использовал функциональный синтаксис через `operator <<`, а не операторный ситнтаксис `a << func`. Последний вариант не предоставляет средств подавления этой рекурсии.

Comment: ааа, т.е. второй метод не является специализацией шаблона? А если добавить `template<>`, то будет специализацией? Спасибо за ответы, кстати. Сам в плюсах никогда бы не разобрался :)

Comment: @pank: Нет, не является. Здесь используется перегрузка (overloading), а не явная специализация (explicit specialization). И специализация тут делу не поможет. Специализации главного шаблона принимаются во внимание только после того, как выполнена дедукция аргументов для главного шаблона. Но в данном примере проблема-то в том и заключается, что невозможно выполнить дедукцию аргументов главного шаблона! И вообще, при работе с шаблонами функций рекомендуется использовать именно перегрузку, и только в узких специальных случаях - явную специализацию (именно из-за "вторичного" статуса последней).

Comment: ещё раз спасибо. До этого момента не знал, что можно делать так: http://ideone.com/ihYSTI.